# How to draw an activity diagram for Usecase that have two actor

Tags: uml, use-case, activity-diagram

I have a use-case with two actors. One actor is into the system like `member` and one other actor is out of the system like `bank` and my system has interaction with these actors. I want to draw an Activity Diagram for this use-case. I have a problem with swim-lanes of this activity diagram.

Should I use three swim-lanes in this activity diagram? How to draw this activity diagram?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you should use at least three swimlanes, one for the system and one for each actors cf my example.[image]